# Float points in subsection

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I have a serious problem here... There is a formating like this:

```
\titleformat{\section}
{\color{Mahogany}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{Mahogany}\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\color{Bittersweet}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{Bittersweet}\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\color{BurntOrange}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{BurntOrange}\thesection}{1em}{}

%-----------------------

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{The awesome section}
Some useful text.

\subsection{The awesome subsection}
Some more useful text.
```

So, I expect now a section formating like this:

```
1 The awesome section
1.1 The awesome subsection
```

but what I get is this:

```
1 The awesome section
1 The awesome subsection
```

Does anyone has a solution for this ?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined all your titles to use the section counter

```
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\color{Bittersweet}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{Bittersweet}\thesection}{1em}{}
```

`\subsection` wants to use `\thesubsection`  and similarly for `\subsubsection`.